# ASP.NET MVC Beginner's question

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Just I am learning MVC,(ofcourse i get enough information from MS Website).I want to quickly
clarify some  details.

1) What is the use of PartialView in MVC,Is it similar to partial update of Ajax?
  I am does the partialView modify the HTML DOM structure?

2)Can i use Response.Redirect() in MVC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Partial View is more like a UserControl. Update Panels are not fully supported (in my eyes a good thing as they add a lot to page size). You can use them as such:

```
<div id="logindisplay">
                <% Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); %>
            </div>
```

2) You can use Response.Redirect in MVC but you may prefer to use RedirectToAction as it will help with your routing if you ever come to change it

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Comment: Also if you need to redirect to something other than an Action, you can simply return Redirect("http://mysite.com");.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not really, a partial view is more a resuable bit of HTML.
2. Yes, you can.

Answer (score 0):

1. Dan is right, you can think of partial view as a "serverside" includes, its a pretty nice way to i.e include a login controller functionality, banner rotator.  You can also make use of the view model for that particular view you are looking at. Take a look at i.e ui templates in mvc2 thats technicaly a partial view.
2. yes you can, but you probably want to use RedirectToAction method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Partial view is special view which renders a portion of view content. It is just like a user control web form application. Partial can be reusable in multiple views. It helps us to reduce code duplication. In other word a partial view enables us to render a view within the parent view